# Possible to open administrator folders without running Explorer as administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, windows-explorer, administrator

In Windows (10), is there a way to open folders as administrator via GUI **without Explorer.exe running as administrator?**

I'd like to easily access my Administrator account's folders from my primary user account (part of the Administrator's group), but without Explorer running constantly with administrator privileges, which would mean all programs run by it will also run with admin privileges. And I'd rather not have Explorer.exe running constantly with admin privileges, given the number of shell extensions I use (and not trusting their coding enough to let them have unrestrained reins).

Comment: Explorer does not run with Administrator permissions. Even an administrator needs to authorize elevation when accessing restricted folders.

Comment: You could give your primary user account rights to view/modify that folder.

Comment: note that "Run as Administrator" is a bit of a misnomer. you are not running with the account "Administrator" but instead as a member of the Group "Administrators". Its really rather odd that the Administrator account itself has files that are meaningful to you. Windows disables the account "Administrator" by default. either way. the proper answer is to grant your user permissions to the profile directory and sub-directories. Admin group membership is only required if you don't have permission to the files in question.